# How to update video's creationTime using Google Photo API

Tags: python, google-photos-api

all.

Can you give me some help?

I have so many videos (mp4) on Google Photo.
And some of them that shot by Casio EX-ZR200 has wrong property creationTime.
The pictures (jpg) has correct creationTime.

MP4 has minus 9 hours time lag.
I think Casio or Google do not consider UTC `+9`.
So, I'm fixing it.

I use python [googleapiclient](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation) and [Google photo API v1](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search).
Now I have all ids of incorrect MP4.

But I can't update creationTime.
Google photo API DOES NOT have update method, right?

What should I do? What API can I use?
If I should use Picasa API or any other, can I use ids that already got by Google photos API?

Thanks

#### 2018/06/19 update

I found [a feature request on Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/110179448) that improve their Google Photo API.
I should be waiting for that..

Comment: You can update photo's metadata using [Picasa API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python#UpdatePhotos). If you don't like that, why not create a script which deletes all original photos and upload them again with the correct timestamp?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try Picasa API. Do you know Is it the same ID that Picasa and Google photo?

Comment: I think Picasa's `photoid` is not the same as Google Photo's one.  I called `gd_client.GetFeed('/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/%s/photoid/%s' % (album_id, '<GooglePhotosOne>'))` but return `Invalid entity id`.

Comment: So you can try the second method that I suggested you

Comment: Thanks, cpinamtz. It's a little bit hard to do that, cos I have almost 3,000 videos to be fixed. And I can't find the way which one is incorrect by Picasa API.